# Prevent LongListMultiSelector from "auto scrolling" when inserting items at the beginning

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls, cimbalino

I am using a LongListMultiSelector to show messages.
Newest messages are at the botton - like in a messenger.
I know have a button in the ListHeaderTemplate, that allows me to load earlier messages and insert them at the top at the list (`ObservableCollection.Insert(0, item);`).

Inserting works, but it looks like that the list scrolls automatically to the last inserted item - it actually does not scroll, but it feels like it scrolls, because after the insert, the new item is displayed, but i rather looking for a solution that keeps the item visible that was the first before the new items where inserted and that i have to do another vertical scroll to the new top to reach the list header again.

Any clues?

*EDIT 1*

consider, `oldFirstItem` is the current first item, then I insert a new item in front of the item. now the new item, becomes the first item, and since the scroll position does not change, the new item is visible: it feels like the list scrolls to the new inserted item, but it only pushed items 1 to n down. what i want is, that it pushes all new items up - into the area that the user does not see - and `oldFirstItem` at the top of the items that are visble.
using ScrollTo makes that list jump.

*EDIT 2*
I added a picture trying to show what I want to achieve. The area above the red line is not visible.[image]

Comment: so you want that oldermessage stick there?

Comment: yes, it should feel like loading earlier messages on the iphone. they should get loaded and added on top without any scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

To get you going, I tried something but could not get it a 100%

Here is a working basic page template which in fact does what you require with messages

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage >

<ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="500" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="DataList" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"></toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

This keeps new messages down, pulling the list up. The scrolling is now disabled. You can easily enclose ScrollViewer in grid and add the button above (like in your picture)

Now the code that would go into the button click

```
    Scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
    Scroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(DataList.ActualHeight);
```

Unfortunately this scrolls the list up BUT if you trigger the second line of code again for example via button click, ScrollToVerticalOffset works. So for some reason ScrollToVerticalOffset is not working right away-after changing VerticalScrollBarVisibility. If you can get this last part figured out, I believe your question would be solved

Comment: you cannot suggest here, you have to give complete answer

Comment: give code and this amount of info to comment ? u gotta be kidding, often solutions here are pointers towards the way to go man ...

Answer (score -1):

The thing that prevents your desired effect is the ListHeader control is at top when you insert item at top. You can do some tricky code to bypass it:

```
var temp = MyLongListMultiSelector.ListHeader; //also works with ListHeaderTemplate
MyLongListMultiSelector.ListHeader = null;
MyObservableCollection.Insert(0, item);    
MyLongListMultiSelector.ListHeader = temp;
```

Or you can make a fake header item and handle the add top event like:

```
MyLongListMultiSelector.Remove(fakeHeaderItem);
MyObservableCollection.Insert(0, item); 
MyObservableCollection.Insert(0, fakeHeaderItem);
```

Comment: this is not the list header he is looking for

Comment: @techloverr What do you mean "the list header he is look for"? From what I see at his question and his edit, he is asking for the effect at EDIT 2:" I added a picture trying to show what I want to achieve."

Answer (score -1):

you can easily achieve this via adding new items to top of the observable collection

```
obsData.Insert(0,newItem)
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654928%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score -2):

If I see... you can use `ScrollTo` method.

```
yourLongListMultiSelector.ScrollTo(yourNewInsertedItem);
```

Comment: hi, no, this does not work, and is also now what i mean. i will edit the original post to explain more.

Comment: I also think the ScrollTo is the only option... if you want to keep the olditem as the top item, you need to get a hold of it and than use the ScrollTo to navigate to it again.

Comment: @kubakista kindly understand question and then answer and do not suggest patches as it is harmful for developers in future